# finding perpendicular bisector given two complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$. Consider the line joining these two points, say $L = \vec{zw} $. How can I find the perpendicular bisector of this line ?

Comment: What exactly does "$L = \vec{zw}$" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction vector from $z$ to $w$ is $(w-z)$ and a vector perpendicular to this direction vector is obtained by multiplying by $i$, which rotates counterclockwise by $90$ degrees. The midpoint between $w$ and $z$ is $(z+w)/2$. So a parametric representation of the perpendicular bisector is
$$
                    l(t)=\frac{1}{2}(z+w)+t(i(w-z)),\;\;\; -\infty < t < \infty.
$$

Comment: shouldn't be $(w-z)/2 $ also

Comment: All you need is $t$ times a vector in a direction perpendicular to the vector from $w$ to $z$; $i(w-z)$ is such a vector, and the length you use for this vector only affects the parameterization, but not the line. The point where the line crosses the segment between $w$ and $z$ is *very* important and must be $(z+w)/2$; otherwise you don't get a bisector.

Answer (score 3):

Points on the perpendicular bisector of the segment joining $z$ and $w$ are characterized by being equidistant from these two points. So points $p\in\mathbb C$ on the line are precisely the solutions $p$ to

$$|p-z| = |p-w|$$